# $4$ vectors can be a set of $\mathbb{R}^3$ subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The question was $4$ vectors can be a basis for $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ ? 
I think from any $4$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ we can find a vector that is linear combination of others in $\mathbb{R}^3$ its because of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ dimension. But I'm not really sure. If I'm right any proof or method that explains ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ has 3 vectors in it. So, 4 vectors cannot form a basis. This is the definition of the dimension of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 1):

The dimension of a vector space is by definition the number of elements of a base (is the same for all the basis). One basis for $\Bbb R^3$ is $\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$.
A set of 4 vectors *can* span $\Bbb R^3$, but it will be linearly dependent.